# Round non-terminating (irrational) BigDecimal properly

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a maths-y problem. I have an irrational BigDecimal that I want to round off however I want to round it *after* it starts repeating itself if that makes sense. So for example if I had

0.76489512147147147147147147147147

I would want it to round to

0.76489512147

as the rest would just be 147 recurring.

Is there Java functionality to do this? Or would I need to implement some sort of algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: The compiler doesn't see those numbers as a series of characters but

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is easily solved by treating the output as a String and applying some regex Kung Fu:

```
// Replace the smallest repeating trailing group with 1 copy of itself
String truncated = a.replaceAll("(.+?)(?=\\1+$).*", "$1");
```

Here's some test code:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.76489512147147147147147147147147");
String s = bd.toString();
// Replace the smallest repeating trailing group with 1 copy of itself
String truncated = s.replaceAll("(.+?)(?=\\1+$).*", "$1");
System.out.println(truncated);
```

Output:

```
0.76489512147
```

Answer (score 1):

The example number you've given is actually rational - irrational numbers (e.g. pi or the square root of 2) never repeat.

You can use the [JScience](http://jscience.org/) library, which has a [Rational](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/Rational.html) class that can precisely represent numbers like 0.764895121[47]-repeating.

Comment: Sorry irrational was the wrong word. I should have said non-terminating.

The problem is I need to output the number to a file and it needs to be as small as possible. But I'll check out that library. Thanks